# Google Analytics, missing a page in some parts of the reports

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4, bug-tracking

It's easiest described by looking at the pictures:

[image]

Now there is a different metric on my landing page displaying this, the top ranking page is not listed in the pages section:

[image]

It appears in one report but doesn't in the other. I tried to change the list of pages that are displayed but I simply found no option. It's confusing because Google analytics understands that there has been traffic on this website but somehow it's not represented in the event log so if you look into the Event log you see 3 Sessions even though it states that there have be 46 alone on one page...

I tried to change the list couldn't find a solution. I tried to google the problem found no useful infos.